Proper alignment of images and text within individual containers
I am trying to align an image closer to its right container border while also trying to align a text closer to the left of its own container border but still give spacing between the two elements between both containers so that the two elements within each containers don't stick too close to one another with a bit of a gap in between like my canva design in the first image below. I got the second image beneath that as my result

intended design
result

Beneath is the specific HTML  for the element I am trying to fix
 <body>
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <div class="about-us-image">
                <img class="about-image"
                src="file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/templatemo_591_villa_agency/assets/images/smiling-handsome-asian-manager-with-modern-device.jpg"
                 alt="smiling-handsome-asian-manager-with-modern-device">
                </img>
            </div>
            <div class="about-us-text">
                <h2><h2 style="color: #56aeff; font-size: 40px; font-family: Arial;">Who We Are</h2>
                <p><p style=font-size:20px;">With more than a decade of experience, we are a trusted team of business and financial planners to help you start your business or retirement in Bali, Indonesia and other islands</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

Below is the specific CSS for this particular element
.about-us-image {
    display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        gap: 45;
    
}

.about-image {
    height: 500px;
        width: 400px;
        box-sizing: border-box;

}

.about-us-text {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-self: start;
    padding: 80px 50px 0 0;
    padding-left:none;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-right: 25px;

If you want to view my full code it's on JSfiddle: full code
I have tried asking other forums on possible solutions but none has worked. I have also tried asking this exact same question before on Stackoverflow but my questions keep being declined on the basis of faulty spelling errors in my code and code being too aligned to the left when in fact all of my codes are already indented. I have also moved my CSS  for this web page into the HTML where before the CSS was an internal file.

First of all, please attach the missing code normally. Check some typos and check for missing symbols.

Your HTML is invalid. The <img> tag does not use a closing tag and you have a <h2> within a <h2>. There may be more errors. Learn to use the W3C HTML Validator.

As you are already using display: flex; for image and text then adding gap:50px would be best to create space between image and text. Below is working example.


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: url('file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/templatemo_591_villa_agency/assets/images/techno%20background.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.data-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px;
}

.about-us-image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  gap: 45;
}

.about-image {
  height: 500px;
  width: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.about-us-text {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-self: start;
  padding: 80px 50px 0 0;
  padding-left: none;
  padding-top: 0%;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
<body>
  <div style="display: flex; gap: 50px;">
    <div class="about-us-image">
      <img class="about-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/17719773/pexels-photo-17719773/free-photo-of-plant-in-flowerpot-on-windowsill.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="smiling-handsome-asian-manager-with-modern-device">
      </img>
    </div>
    <div class="about-us-text">
      <h2>
        <h2 style="color: #56aeff; font-size: 40px; font-family: Arial;">Who We Are</h2>
        <p>
          <p style=font-size:20px; ">With more than a decade of experience, we are a trusted team of business and
                    financial planners to help you start your business or retirement in Bali, Indonesia and other
                    islands</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>




thank you for the input but my image is too far right and too close to the text after I use your code. How do I give a space between the text and image from the border of each container so that there is a gap between them?

@Samuel that's exactly what I have done, creating space between image and text. If you want more space then increase gap to 100px or whatever you like.

@Meet You have continued with the same HTML errors the OP has.

@Rob OP mentioned that he wanted space between image at left and text at right. I have added space between them using gap: 10px. If I have got anything wrong then please do share.

I already said. See my comment below his question. The HTML is invalid.

@Rob it might be mine fault because more I read OP question I am getting more confused about what he wants.

You could use grid to create the two 'halves' of the layout and then position the elements within their appropriate areas.
This snippet simply replaces the flex on the parent with a two column grid and then centers the image within its area.
You can of course move the text within its area if you want more spacing but the result looks fairly like the desired picture you gave.


<style>
  .about-us-image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .about-image {
    height: 500px;
    width: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .about-us-text {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 100px;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    align-self: start;
    padding: 80px 50px 0 0;
    padding-left: none;
    padding-top: 0%;
    padding-right: 25px;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;">
    <div class="about-us-image">
      <img class="about-image" src="https://i.sstatic.net/xFCKtHKi.png" alt="smiling-handsome-asian-manager-with-modern-device">
      </img>
    </div>
    <div class="about-us-text">
      <h2>
        <h2 style="color: #56aeff; font-size: 40px; font-family: Arial;">Who We Are</h2>
        <p>
          <p style=font-size:20px; ">With more than a decade of experience, we are a trusted team of business and financial planners to help you start your business or retirement in Bali, Indonesia and other islands</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>



For narrow viewports I imagine you'll want to include some media query which perhaps goes to a single column grid so the text doesn't get too squished.
[Note I haven't tried to mend the HTML - use something like the W3C validator to iron out problems.]

What happens if he fixes his broken HTML and your solution no longer works?

Actually as the broken HTML is within one of the elements that are placed by the grid, which is the change I made, then of course that might muck up the inside of the right hand side but won't affect the grid which has just two elements - and that's the layout this question is about.

@Rob i tried making modifications to the code and it seems to be back to its faulty layout again, is this what you meant that it no longer works?

@AHaworth I implemented yourt cfodes and the image is pushed too far left in tits own container while the text is perfectly centered in its container
